# How do I include an unofficial typescript definition file in my project?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, paperjs, typescript-typings

I'm trying to include a typings definition file that is not located on the definitelytyped github repo so I don't think I can install it using typings from my terminal. Does anyone know how I'm supposed to include this in my Angular 2 typescript project?

The definition file I'm trying to include is one for the paper.js library located here https://github.com/sqwk/paper.d.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can install it using typings directly from github:

```
typings install github:sqwk/paper.d.ts/paper.d.ts --save --global
```

More information on typings valid locations [here](https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/commands.md)

*sqwk/paper.d.ts* - is org/repo.

*/paper.d.ts* - is the path.

You can also define specific commit by adding `#commit-id` to the path:

```
typings install github:sqwk/paper.d.ts/paper.d.ts#0c45e2c25d3190fbedfcee998074356e58a392a9 --save --global
```

Answer (score 0):

In you root project folder, create a `manual_typings` folder and add the `paper.d.ts` file. When you run the Typescript compiler, it'll read the definition and won't complain about this lib. You can call `manual_typings` folder to any name you want. This is the pattern I follow.

Answer (score 0):

Where you place the files depends on how you have you have configured your [tsconfig.json](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/typescript-configuration.html) file. The "moduleResolution" property can be set to Classic or Node, this will define how TypeScript will search your folder structure for paper.d.ts. The details on how it will look through you folder structure can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html).